# problem with i18n (internationalization) with Spring and Velocity

Tags: spring, internationalization, locale, interceptor

I am having a problem in setting up internationalization with Spring.
Here is my config.

```
    <bean id="messageSource"
            class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="localization" />
    </bean>
    <!-- declare the resolver -->
    <bean id="localeResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
            <property name="defaultLocale" value="sv" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:interceptors>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

It always showing me English even when I request with `?locale=sv` (Swedish).

I am using Spring with Velocity.

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did:

- First copied `messages_xx.properties` in `src/main/resources` 
  I could not get it to work with name `messages_xx_xx` (messages_en_us)
- Then just added following configs to xxxx_servlet.xml context

  ```
  <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
          <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
          <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
  </bean>
  ```

```
    <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

- Used `#springMessages('message.title')` in my `*.vm`

that was it.